# Passing a length as an argument to raisebox

Tags: graphics, positioning, lengths

**To summarize it:** I think `\depth` is losing its information somehow and I was not able to fix it.

I am trying to place an image inline and to adjust its vertical position with `\raisebox`, like so:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newlength\depth
\newcommand\IMG{\raisebox{-\depth}{\includegraphics[scale=0.025]{example-image}}\xspace}

\begin{document}

\settodepth{\depth}{g}

text \IMG text \the\depth

\end{document}
```

[image: with settodepth]

So the `-\depth` seems to be doing nothing.

Even if I use `\setlength{\depth}{1.94444pt}` instead of `\settodepth{\depth}{g}` (in preamble or not), the outcome doesn't change.

However, if I explicitly put the `-1.94444pt` value in place of `-\depth` everything works fine:

```
\newcommand\IMG{\raisebox{-1.94444pt}{\includegraphics[scale=0.025]{example-image}}\xspace}
```

[image: desired result]

Therefore, how do I make `\raisebox` see the length stored in `\depth`?

Comment: The box create by `\includegraphics` has a depth of 0pt (unless you use the adjustbox positioning options).  OTOH, `\dp\strutbox` is the depth of `\strut`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\depth` is a standard latex command but it is only usable within the argument of `\makebox` and similar commands, refering to the original size of the box.

You have `\newlength\depth` which has defined a new length register of the same name but the original use of `\depth` in thebox arguments is unrelated to the use fo `\depth` that you have enabled outside of those arguments.

You should use a name other than `\depth`

Comment: So I spent hours of troubleshooting and the problem was me... :( Live and learn, I guess, thank you David Carlisle.

Answer (score 3):

Besides `\depth` being a bad name, as already explained, if you want that your image has the same height and depth of a “g” in the current font, you can use the exact measures:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%\newcommand\IMG{%
%  \raisebox{-\fontchardp\font`g}{\includegraphics[scale=0.025]{example-image}}%
%}

\newcommand\IMG{%
  \raisebox{-\fontchardp\font`g}{%
    \includegraphics[
      height=\dimexpr\fontcharht\font`g+\fontchardp\font`g\relax
    ]{example-image}}%
}

\begin{document}

text g\IMG\ text

\LARGE text g\IMG\ text

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to match a math Greek letter, you can exploit the uniform way they're defined, from mathgroup 1. Here I use `\beta` so it has a depth.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_new:Nn \leone_get_charcode_from_mathcode:N
 {
  \int_mod:nn { #1 } { 256 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \leone_greek_char_ht:N
 {
  \fontcharht\textfont 1 ~ \leone_get_charcode_from_mathcode:N #1
 }
\cs_new:Nn \leone_greek_char_dp:N
 {
  \fontchardp\textfont 1 ~ \leone_get_charcode_from_mathcode:N #1
 }
\cs_new:Nn \leone_greek_char_total:N
 {
  \dim_eval:n { \leone_greek_char_ht:N #1 + \leone_greek_char_dp:N #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand\IMG {}
 {
  \use:c { check@mathfonts }
  \raisebox{-\dim_eval:n { \leone_greek_char_dp:N \beta }}
   {
    \includegraphics
     [
      height=\leone_greek_char_total:N \beta
     ]
     {example-image}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

text $\beta$\IMG\ text

\LARGE text $\beta$\IMG\ text

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `\alpha` instead of `\beta`:

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to do this for a greek letter instead of "g"? (like ```$\alpha$``` for example)

Comment: @Leone Yes, it's possible, see edited answer.

Answer (score 2):

Is it what you want?

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{mwe}

\newlength\depth
\newcommand\IMG{\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics[scale=0.025]{example-image}}\xspace}

\begin{document}

\settodepth{\depth}{g}

text \IMG text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Kind of. I want the exact depth of my text (regardless its size). If I use ```-0.5\height``` it gives me a little more vertical offset than what I want

Comment: @Leone: You can adjust the spacing with a coefficient slightly smaller than 0.5, to be found by trial and error.

Comment: You have a point there, this is definitely one way to do it, but I would like a more elegant solution like using ```\settodepth{\mydepth}{g}``` (without guessing anything).